# Why does my makefile file return error 193?

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

```
g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/BSTDugum.cpp -o ./lib/BSTDugum.o
g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/Kontrol.cpp -o ./lib/Kontrol.o
g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/Program.cpp -o ./lib/Program.o
./lib/BSTDugum.o ./lib/Kontrol.o ./lib/Program.o -o ./bin/program
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\Users\monster\Desktop\ODEV_3\lib\BSTDugum.o, ./lib/BSTDugum.o 
./lib/Kontrol.o ./lib/Program.o -o ./bin/program, ...) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'program' failed
mingw32-make: *** [program] Error 193
```

I can't solve this problem everything looks good. I can debug this program on visual studio This is my makefile file :

```
program:BSTDugum.o Kontrol.o Program.o
    ./lib/BSTDugum.o ./lib/Kontrol.o ./lib/Program.o -o ./bin/program
BSTDugum.o:
    g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/BSTDugum.cpp -o ./lib/BSTDugum.o
Kontrol.o:
    g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/Kontrol.cpp -o ./lib/Kontrol.o
Program.o:
    g++ -I "./include" -c ./src/Program.cpp -o ./lib/Program.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `g++` or the linker you'd like to use first on the line supposed to link your program:

```
program:BSTDugum.o Kontrol.o Program.o
        g++ ./lib/BSTDugum.o ./lib/Kontrol.o ./lib/Program.o -o ./bin/program
```

As it is right now, you're trying to use the object file `./lib/BSTDugum.o` as the linking command.